# Departure rate of $k$ customers in a queue

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, queueing-theory, birth-death-process

$\textbf{Soft question:}$ If the probability of a customer leaving the queue (system) is $\frac{1}{4}$, am I right to say that the departure rate of a single customer is $\mu=\frac{1}{4}$, and that the departure rate of $k$ customers is $k\mu = \frac{k}{4}$ in the $M/M/\infty$ system?

Some clarification will be great!

Comment: Under what context do you talk about a "probability of a customer leaving the queue" in the $M/M/\infty$ to begin with? That is, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Ah by that I mean the probability of a customer being served, and thus he/she leaves the queue (system).

Comment: Under what circumstances would you "flip the $\frac14$-biased coin" to determine if the customer leaves the system or not? I remain unsure if this is a weird way of describing the departure rate, or something that cannot occur in a continuous-time Markov chain at all.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Hmm you do have a point. How about viewing it as a probability $\frac{1}{4}$ of death in a population of $k$ many people, when the birth rate/parameter is a constant $\lambda$? Does that help?